# Unable to get json from within res object

Tags: node.js, httpresponse

I have a small server and small client. The code has been extrapolated to focus on the problem at hand.

I have a client that sends a POST request to the server. The server responds with a json object. I am unable to see the json response object from within the node.js client. However, if I make a curl request, I can see it...

//SERVER

```
    var restify = require('restify'),
            Logger = require('bunyan'),
            api = require('./routes/api'),
            util = require('util'),
            fs = require('fs');

    //START SERVER
    var server = restify.createServer({ name: 'image-server', log: log })
     server.listen(7000, function () {
     console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url)
    })

    server.use(restify.fullResponse());
    server.use(restify.bodyParser());

    //change from github
    var user = {username: "usr", password: "pwd"};

    //auth middleware
    server.use(function(req,res,next){
            if(req.params.username==user.username && req.params.password == user.password){
                    return next();
            }else{
                    res.send(401);
            }
    });

    server.post('/doc/', function(req,res){
            var objToJson = {"result" : "success", "user" : "simon", "location" : "someloc"};
            console.log("saved new doc. res: " + util.inspect(objToJson));
            res.send(objToJson);
    });
```

//CLIENT

```
    var formdata = require('form-data');
    var request = require('request');
    var util = require('util');
    var fs = require('fs');

    var form = new formdata();
    form.append('username', 'usr');
    form.append('password', 'pwd');
    form.append('user', 'someemail@gmail.com');
    form.append('file', fs.createReadStream('/some/file.png'));
    form.append('filename', "roger123131.png");

    form.submit('http://0.0.0.0:7000/doc', function(err, res) {
      console.log(res.statusCode);
      console.log(res.body);
      console.log(  "here." + util.inspect(res));
      process.exit();
    });
```

In the client, I use form-data module. I need to send over the file, though I'm not sure if this is related/pertinent to the problem at hand.

//CURL REQUEST

```
curl -v --form username=usr --form password=pwd --form file=@/tmp/0000b.jpg --form user=someemail http://0.0.0.0:7000/doc
```

The output of the curl request works. My question is, why can i not see the json response when I dump the response object in my node.js client code, but I can when making a request using curl? I'm sure the answer is simple...

EDIT: Here is the output of the node.js client, showing the response object with no evidence of the json object/string:

```
200
undefined
here.{ _readableState: 
   { highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: [],
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: false,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: true,
     calledRead: true,
     sync: false,
     needReadable: true,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     objectMode: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events: { end: [Function: responseOnEnd], readable: [Function] },
  _maxListeners: 10,
  socket: 
   { _connecting: false,
     _handle: 
      { fd: 10,
    writeQueueSize: 0,
    owner: [Circular],
    onread: [Function: onread],
    reading: true },
     _readableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
    buffer: [],
    length: 0,
    pipes: null,
    pipesCount: 0,
    flowing: false,
    ended: false,
    endEmitted: false,
    reading: true,
    calledRead: true,
    sync: false,
    needReadable: true,
    emittedReadable: false,
    readableListening: false,
    objectMode: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    ranOut: false,
    awaitDrain: 0,
    readingMore: false,
    decoder: null,
    encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
    finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
    _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
    free: [Function],
    close: [Object],
    agentRemove: [Function],
    drain: [Function: ondrain],
    error: [Function: socketErrorListener] },
     _maxListeners: 10,
     _writableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
    objectMode: false,
    needDrain: false,
    ending: false,
    ended: false,
    finished: false,
    decodeStrings: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    length: 0,
    writing: false,
    sync: false,
    bufferProcessing: false,
    onwrite: [Function],
    writecb: null,
    writelen: 0,
    buffer: [],
    errorEmitted: false },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: false,
     onend: [Function: socketOnEnd],
     destroyed: false,
     bytesRead: 587,
     _bytesDispatched: 23536,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     parser: 
      { _headers: [],
    _url: '',
    onHeaders: [Function: parserOnHeaders],
    onHeadersComplete: [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
    onBody: [Function: parserOnBody],
    onMessageComplete: [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
    socket: [Circular],
    incoming: [Circular],
    maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
    onIncoming: [Function: parserOnIncomingClient] },
     _httpMessage: 
      { domain: null,
    _events: [Object],
    _maxListeners: 10,
    output: [],
    outputEncodings: [],
    writable: true,
    _last: false,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
    sendDate: false,
    _headerSent: true,
    _header: 'POST /doc HTTP/1.1\r\ncontent-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------994987473640480876924123\r\nHost: 0.0.0.0:7000\r\nContent-Length: 23351\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n',
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _hangupClose: false,
    socket: [Circular],
    connection: [Circular],
    agent: [Object],
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/doc',
    _headers: [Object],
    _headerNames: [Object],
    parser: [Object],
    res: [Circular] },
     ondata: [Function: socketOnData] },
  connection: 
   { _connecting: false,
     _handle: 
      { fd: 10,
    writeQueueSize: 0,
    owner: [Circular],
    onread: [Function: onread],
    reading: true },
     _readableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
    buffer: [],
    length: 0,
    pipes: null,
    pipesCount: 0,
    flowing: false,
    ended: false,
    endEmitted: false,
    reading: true,
    calledRead: true,
    sync: false,
    needReadable: true,
    emittedReadable: false,
    readableListening: false,
    objectMode: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    ranOut: false,
    awaitDrain: 0,
    readingMore: false,
    decoder: null,
    encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
    finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
    _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
    free: [Function],
    close: [Object],
    agentRemove: [Function],
    drain: [Function: ondrain],
    error: [Function: socketErrorListener] },
     _maxListeners: 10,
     _writableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
    objectMode: false,
    needDrain: false,
    ending: false,
    ended: false,
    finished: false,
    decodeStrings: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    length: 0,
    writing: false,
    sync: false,
    bufferProcessing: false,
    onwrite: [Function],
    writecb: null,
    writelen: 0,
    buffer: [],
    errorEmitted: false },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: false,
     onend: [Function: socketOnEnd],
     destroyed: false,
     bytesRead: 587,
     _bytesDispatched: 23536,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     parser: 
      { _headers: [],
    _url: '',
    onHeaders: [Function: parserOnHeaders],
    onHeadersComplete: [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
    onBody: [Function: parserOnBody],
    onMessageComplete: [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
    socket: [Circular],
    incoming: [Circular],
    maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
    onIncoming: [Function: parserOnIncomingClient] },
     _httpMessage: 
      { domain: null,
    _events: [Object],
    _maxListeners: 10,
    output: [],
    outputEncodings: [],
    writable: true,
    _last: false,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
    sendDate: false,
    _headerSent: true,
    _header: 'POST /doc HTTP/1.1\r\ncontent-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------994987473640480876924123\r\nHost: 0.0.0.0:7000\r\nContent-Length: 23351\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n',
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _hangupClose: false,
    socket: [Circular],
    connection: [Circular],
    agent: [Object],
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/doc',
    _headers: [Object],
    _headerNames: [Object],
    parser: [Object],
    res: [Circular] },
     ondata: [Function: socketOnData] },
  httpVersion: '1.1',
  complete: false,
  headers: 
   { 'content-type': 'application/json',
     'content-length': '56',
     'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
     'access-control-allow-headers': 'Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, Api-Version, Response-Time',
     'access-control-allow-methods': 'POST',
     'access-control-expose-headers': 'Api-Version, Request-Id, Response-Time',
     connection: 'Keep-Alive',
     'content-md5': '/HLlB0jKu9S+l17eGyJfxg==',
     date: 'Wed, 25 Jun 2014 15:40:00 GMT',
     server: 'image-server',
     'request-id': 'f7ca8390-fc7e-11e3-aa4e-e9c4573d9f1d',
     'response-time': '4' },
  trailers: {},
  _pendings: [],
  _pendingIndex: 0,
  url: '',
  method: null,
  statusCode: 200,
  client: 
   { _connecting: false,
     _handle: 
      { fd: 10,
    writeQueueSize: 0,
    owner: [Circular],
    onread: [Function: onread],
    reading: true },
     _readableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
    buffer: [],
    length: 0,
    pipes: null,
    pipesCount: 0,
    flowing: false,
    ended: false,
    endEmitted: false,
    reading: true,
    calledRead: true,
    sync: false,
    needReadable: true,
    emittedReadable: false,
    readableListening: false,
    objectMode: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    ranOut: false,
    awaitDrain: 0,
    readingMore: false,
    decoder: null,
    encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
    finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
    _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
    free: [Function],
    close: [Object],
    agentRemove: [Function],
    drain: [Function: ondrain],
    error: [Function: socketErrorListener] },
     _maxListeners: 10,
     _writableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
    objectMode: false,
    needDrain: false,
    ending: false,
    ended: false,
    finished: false,
    decodeStrings: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    length: 0,
    writing: false,
    sync: false,
    bufferProcessing: false,
    onwrite: [Function],
    writecb: null,
    writelen: 0,
    buffer: [],
    errorEmitted: false },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: false,
     onend: [Function: socketOnEnd],
     destroyed: false,
     bytesRead: 587,
     _bytesDispatched: 23536,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     parser: 
      { _headers: [],
    _url: '',
    onHeaders: [Function: parserOnHeaders],
    onHeadersComplete: [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
    onBody: [Function: parserOnBody],
    onMessageComplete: [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
    socket: [Circular],
    incoming: [Circular],
    maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
    onIncoming: [Function: parserOnIncomingClient] },
     _httpMessage: 
      { domain: null,
    _events: [Object],
    _maxListeners: 10,
    output: [],
    outputEncodings: [],
    writable: true,
    _last: false,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
    sendDate: false,
    _headerSent: true,
    _header: 'POST /doc HTTP/1.1\r\ncontent-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------994987473640480876924123\r\nHost: 0.0.0.0:7000\r\nContent-Length: 23351\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n',
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _hangupClose: false,
    socket: [Circular],
    connection: [Circular],
    agent: [Object],
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/doc',
    _headers: [Object],
    _headerNames: [Object],
    parser: [Object],
    res: [Circular] },
     ondata: [Function: socketOnData] },
  _consuming: true,
  _dumped: false,
  httpVersionMajor: 1,
  httpVersionMinor: 1,
  upgrade: false,
  req: 
   { domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Object], response: [Function] },
     _maxListeners: 10,
     output: [],
     outputEncodings: [],
     writable: true,
     _last: false,
     chunkedEncoding: false,
     shouldKeepAlive: true,
     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
     sendDate: false,
     _headerSent: true,
     _header: 'POST /doc HTTP/1.1\r\ncontent-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------994987473640480876924123\r\nHost: 0.0.0.0:7000\r\nContent-Length: 23351\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n',
     _hasBody: true,
     _trailer: '',
     finished: true,
     _hangupClose: false,
     socket: 
      { _connecting: false,
    _handle: [Object],
    _readableState: [Object],
    readable: true,
    domain: null,
    _events: [Object],
    _maxListeners: 10,
    _writableState: [Object],
    writable: true,
    allowHalfOpen: false,
    onend: [Function: socketOnEnd],
    destroyed: false,
    bytesRead: 587,
    _bytesDispatched: 23536,
    _pendingData: null,
    _pendingEncoding: '',
    parser: [Object],
    _httpMessage: [Circular],
    ondata: [Function: socketOnData] },
     connection: 
      { _connecting: false,
    _handle: [Object],
    _readableState: [Object],
    readable: true,
    domain: null,
    _events: [Object],
    _maxListeners: 10,
    _writableState: [Object],
    writable: true,
    allowHalfOpen: false,
    onend: [Function: socketOnEnd],
    destroyed: false,
    bytesRead: 587,
    _bytesDispatched: 23536,
    _pendingData: null,
    _pendingEncoding: '',
    parser: [Object],
    _httpMessage: [Circular],
    ondata: [Function: socketOnData] },
     agent: 
      { domain: null,
    _events: [Object],
    _maxListeners: 10,
    options: {},
    requests: {},
    sockets: [Object],
    maxSockets: 5,
    createConnection: [Function] },
     socketPath: undefined,
     method: 'POST',
     path: '/doc',
     _headers: 
      { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------994987473640480876924123',
    host: '0.0.0.0:7000',
    'content-length': 23351 },
     _headerNames: 
      { 'content-type': 'content-type',
    host: 'Host',
    'content-length': 'Content-Length' },
     parser: 
      { _headers: [],
    _url: '',
    onHeaders: [Function: parserOnHeaders],
    onHeadersComplete: [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
    onBody: [Function: parserOnBody],
    onMessageComplete: [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
    socket: [Object],
    incoming: [Circular],
    maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
    onIncoming: [Function: parserOnIncomingClient] },
     res: [Circular] },
  pipe: [Function],
  addListener: [Function],
  on: [Function],
  pause: [Function],
  resume: [Function],
  read: [Function] }
```

Comment: What do you mean by CLIENT? It does not look like that code would run on any browser.

Comment: By client, are you referring to the browser? If yes, have you tried checking the request payload using the network tools?

Comment: Ttry to use instead of res.send(objToJson); the following: res.send(JSON.stringify(objToJson));

Comment: I have. Makes no difference (apart from the formating). Curl sees the response. My node.js client doesn't.

Comment: at the git-hub site of form-data within an example it is written to close the form-submit with a res.resume(); as posted from Daniel below. Have you tried this already?

Comment: Are you sure you can reach your server throught http://0.0.0.0 i would prefer the normal localhost:7000.

Comment: res.resume(): Yep i've tried.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 vs localhost?!? I get a response object, I just can't see json object/string in it. Maybe I should the res object output, if that would be helpful. EDIT: Of course, I won't be using 0.0.0.0 in production, but for the purposes of this question, it is fine. And to make clear, I do get through to the server. See my point about what happens when I use curl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution from the the request page (https://github.com/mikeal/request), which requires a small change to the client code:

```
var r = request.post('http://service.com/upload', function optionalCallback (err, httpResponse, body) {
if (err) {
 return console.error('upload failed:', err);
}
console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
})
var form = r.form()
form.append('my_field', 'my_value')
form.append('my_buffer', new Buffer([1, 2, 3]))
form.append('my_file', fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, 'doodle.png')))
form.append('remote_file', request('http://google.com/doodle.png'))
```

Answer (score 0):

from the [docs](https://github.com/felixge/node-form-data),

```
form.submit('http://example.org/', function(err, res) {
  // res – response object (http.IncomingMessage)  //
  res.resume(); // for node-0.10.x
});
```

Your callback has three parameters, and the response is in the second one.

Comment: Yep. My mistake. When trying out different things i added in the different paramters, including the res.resume(). I'll change my question to reflect that. It still does not work though...